# How to add personal phone number to multiple Twitter accounts?

Tags: twitter, mobile, twitter-api

I have a personal twitter account, with my personal phone number attached to it. I want to create a twitter app (bot). I created a new twitter account for this bot then went [here](https://apps.twitter.com/app/new) to register the app. But it gives me the error:

> Error You must add your mobile phone to your Twitter profile before creating an application. Please read https://support.twitter.com/articles/110250-adding-your-mobile-number-to-your-account-via-web for more information.

So, I'll have to add my personal phone number (I only have access to my own phone number) to this account as well. No problem. According to this [FAQ](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/phone-number-faqs) we can add a single phone number to up to 10 accounts:

> You can add your phone number to up to 10 accounts. It’s important to note that only the account most recently linked to this phone number can perform SMS commands and receive SMS notifications for account activity like Direct Messages, new followers, Retweets, etc. Any other accounts you have associated with your phone number will not be able to edit Text notifications settings. Each account that has your phone number associated with it will still receive SMS text messages for password reset requests or security features like login verification.

Except when I go to [settings](https://twitter.com/settings/add_phone) and enter my phone number, I get an error:

> The phone number you're trying to use is already associated with another Twitter account.
>   To add your phone, please remove it from any other accounts.

What gives? Can I add my phone number to up to 10 accounts or not? If *not* then how do I create a bot with a second twitter account if I don't have another phone number?